# ImportRrror: no module named 'psycopg2'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, importerror

I'm attempting to use PostgreSQL as my data base and I'm running into an issue when I try to start my server.  Here's what I'm doing:

- I have a virtual environment set up and activated
- Django 1.8.4 is installed
- psycopg2 2.5.2 is installed
- wheel 0.24.0 is installed

I'm using python 3.4.

Adding pip freeze output as requested:

```
Django==1.8.4
psycopg2==2.5.2
wheel==0.24.0
```

when I run the server using the default sqlite3 db I have no issue; it runs fine.  As soon as I switch over to postgres I get the following error: 
ImportError: no module named psycopg2.

`pip install psycopg2` wasn't working so I installed psycopg2 from github using this command: `pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win64-py34#egg=psycopg2`

Guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the output from your `pip install psycopg2`? Are there any errors? Can you `import psycopg2` from a Python shell?

Comment: Note this comment on the repository, "Since psycopg2 is for PostgreSQL, you'll obviousely want to have that installed first."  Do you have postgresql installed?

Comment: Joseph, pip install psycopg2 returns the following error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL is up and running; I can log in and create db's from the command line.

Comment: @Jaime Have you installed Visual C++ 10?

Comment: It is now, but I'm still getting the same error and I don't see vcvarsall.bat in the expected location ...\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are in Windows. For windows, you need to download and install from the binary files. You can download the installers from here.

http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Make sure you select the correct file based on architecture and python version.

After installing the psycopg2 with the installers, re-create your virtual environments to have the plugin working.

Alternatively you can download and install C++ re-distributables from msdn download centre and then try with `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Ok, so I've basically tried everything here and I'm sure it's worked for the folks who posted a solution.  Thank you all for the help.  However nothing I tried resolved the problem.  I either had issues installing psycopg2 or once installed I had the ImportError described above.  I'm gonna try running postgresql and django on OS X.  Hope I have better luck with OS X.

Comment: There is one other issue you need to look into. Even if you are in x64 system, the browsers are not. So if you use the default installer from python, it is highly likely that you downloaded the 32 bit one. So make sure you have the proper architecture versions installed.

Comment: To add to Jamie's comment, I downloaded the 32bit version as per the link above and then did `pip install psycopg2` in my virtual environment. This worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

It is important to specify operating system you are on, as I guess from comment you are using windows.

On windows if you do not wont to install Visual C++ libraries you can just download whl file of the package.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg

choose correct architecture and python version for you and run

```
pip install path/to/packagename.whl
```

make sure you are using pip version 6 or newer

Comment: Windows 7.  sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score -1):

Before you  install psycopg2 please isntall sudo apt-get build-dep python-psycopg2